# Correct way to loop through rows and columns with "Copy of a slice" warnings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a function that I'm using to log transform individual values of a dataframe based a source dataframe and a list of columns that are passed in.

```
def split(columns, start_df):
    df = start_df[columns].copy()
    numeric_features = df.select_dtypes(exclude = ["object"]).columns
    for cols in numeric_features:
        for rows in range(0,train_num.shape[0]):

            # Offending row
            train_num[cols][rows] = np.log(train_num[cols][rows])
```

Since the df and the list of columns will be unknown and the columns may come from another df as `.columns.tolist()`, is there a way to work around this warning without the column index (because it may not match)?

It's the only thing I can think of that's messing up the model I'm making.

I have tried the below, but still getting the warning as well but I'm out of ideas.

```
train_num.loc[cols][rows] = np.log(train_num.loc[cols][rows])
```

This give me an error: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'where'

```
train_num[cols][rows].where(train_num[cols][rows] > 0, 
                            np.log(train_num[cols][rows], 
                            train_num[cols][rows]))
```

What's strange is this section in the same function is throwing the same warning as well, hopefully it's the same fix!

```
X_train.loc[:, numeric_features] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.loc[:, numeric_features])
X_val.loc[:, numeric_features] = scaler.transform(X_val.loc[:, numeric_features])
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: try to make a copy of initial DataFrame by `ndf = pd.copy(df)` and edit new copy.

Comment: Is how I have it in the function df = start_df[columns].copy() not the best way to call a copy of the df? Edit: tried the suggested but got the following error: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'copy'"

Comment: my mistake, it's `ndf = df.copy()` : [for more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

Comment: I don't have the full picture, but a question: Why don't you use `train_num.at[rows, cols] = np.log(train_num.at[rows, cols])`? You could use `[rows, cols]`, `.loc[rows, cols]` as well, but the best access to individual values is `.at[]` (or `.iat[]`). I guess your problems stems from the double brackets `[][]` instead of `[,]`.

Comment: `train_num[cols][rows]` is a scalar, no `np.ndarray`. And a scalar doesn't have the `.where` method. Can't you do it for the full column at once: `train_num[cols].where(train_num[cols] > 0, np.log(train_num[cols], train_num[cols]))`?

Comment: @nipun, I think I have that in my code above only I'm slicing the columns I want as I'm making my copy. Is that what you're thinking is getting me into trouble?

Comment: @Timus Unfortunately, I have valid zeros across many fields, so I wouldn't be able to do that. Not shown is a conditional that checks if the value of the field is !=0 before this code is evaluated.

Comment: But `np.log` doesn't have a problem with `0` (output is `-Inf` for `0`)? Btw., there was a bracket mismatch in the code: `train_num[cols].where(train_num[cols] > 0, np.log(train_num[cols]), train_num[cols])`.

Comment: @Timus - that seemed to work. Thanks for the tip! I did have to change the last argument to inplace=True. Seems like it's the difference between np.where() and df.where(). Would have liked to not have to do a blanket replace of all pos/neg np.infs and get a thousand "thou shalt not log a zero" errors.